# Django - 'User' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

When i am passing `instance1` in context it giving error  `'User' object is not iterable`. I want to display Name in Template of `pk`. Example `http://localhost:8000/users/15/profile-update/` `pk=15`

```
 def userProfileUpdate(request, pk):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=User.objects.get(id=pk))
            p_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, 
                                     request.FILES,
                                     instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=pk))
            if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
                u_form.save()
                p_form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Profile Updated!!!')
                return redirect('users')
        else:
            instance1 = User.objects.get(id=pk)
            u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=User.objects.get(id=pk))
            p_form = UserProfileForm(instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=pk))
        context ={
            'object': instance1, # This is giving the error
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }
        return render(request, 'users/userprofile.html', context)

TypeError at /users/15/profile-update/
'User' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/users/15/profile-update/
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 165
Python Executable:  /home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-njoxc1BQ/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

Comment: Can you try this:  `code` instance1 = User.objects.filter(id=pk)?

Comment: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.

Comment: copy and paste the whole error to the question

Comment: @JPG Please Checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the ans. It does not take object name instead we should put name different thant object. Example

> object12

```
context ={
            'object12': instance1, # Change here
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }
```

and in template we can access it as a `{{ object12.first_name }}`

Answer (score 1):

user `request.user` instead of `User.objects.get(id=pk)` and `request.user.userprofile` instead of `UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=pk))`

Comment: ok just keep this as it is just for test. `UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=pk))`

Comment: use instance=pk